# FileSystemWatcher returns FileNotFoundException

Tags: .net, windows-services, filesystemwatcher

I'm developing a Windows Service application which monitors a CSV file in "C:\Program Files (x86)\My Directory\My Data". The service is able to read/write to this location. I've tested writing a text file to the directory on service start and everything seems to be cool to this point.

My `OnChanged` handler for `FileSystemWatcher`, fires off when the CSV file is updated. But on calling the following line:

`Dim myStream As Stream = New FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)`

I get a `FileNotFoundException` even though the file exists. By this point, I've checked the file permission and tried running my service with my server's Administrator account, yet there is no success.

Any thoughts on about this behavior?

Comment: Your program is liable to be subjected to *file system redirection*, a 64-bit app will see files in c:\program files, a 32-bit app is redirected to c:\program files (x86).  That probably has something to do with it, your question is insufficiently documented to make the call.

Comment: Even though a 64-bit app, I've explicitly made a static reference to "Program Files (x86)" folder. I've still been playing around with this. It seems that the problem occurs in the block where I check `If e.ChangeType = WatcherChangeTypes.Changed` and then set `watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = False` to disable duplicate raising of the OnChanged handler.

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure while using `FileSystemWatcher` that the file you are trying to access is not locked by another process.

`FileSystemWatcher` triggers `OnChanged` event when the file is created - NOT when the file is accessible to other processes.

Comment: The file has already been created and exists. I'm also sure that it is not locked because I tried to use a copy of it in `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\` and tried to update the file using notepad - but I still get `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: OK but I'm not talking about accessing it from windows after it failed. At that point the file could be released by the writing process.  Try to put `Thread.Sleep(1000);` before creating FileStream.  Don't forget to add:  
`using System.Threading;`